# SQL Server: How to pass data table to a stored procedure as an input parameter?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datatable, parameter-passing

I have a data table which is filled within my application with some values that user has entered them via an excel file.  My Application targer .net framework is 2.0 and I can NOT change it to 3.0 or 3.5 in order to use LINQ feature.

So, I have to send my data table values to a stored procedure and contribute them in a join operation.

Is it a good solution or not? If yes, How can I send my Data table to Stored procedure as an input parameter?

Thank you

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784851/passing-a-datatable-into-a-stored-procedure-is-there-a-better-way

Answer (score 2):

By using table-valued parameters you can send data to the SQLServer stored procedure. This user-defined type represents the definition of a table structure and is compatible with SQLServer 2008 and next versions.

You can find example and more information referring to this msdn [aritcle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**Large Complex:** For large complex data I'd probably get your data into a *.csv file (if it's not already that way in Excel), use .Net to BCP it into #temp tables, and then on that same connection call the proc and have the proc always know to look for the data in the #temp tables.  BCP is the fasted way to get large chunks of data into SQLServer.

**Medium Size:** If the size of the data is small then you could format it as XML and send that to the proc.  Here's a quick example using C# http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=107

**Small Delimited:** For small list type data you might be able to get away with sending it as comma delimited string of values. This is very handy when sending a list of ID's to a proc (http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)